# Where can I see how many (EXP) points I need to get the next skill point?

Tags: starfield

From time to time I get a new skill point. This will be clearly shown on the screen and with a triumphal fanfare sound:

[image]

But where can I see how many experience points I still need to get the next skill point?

How does this value increase over time?

*(I don't assume that the amount of needed experience points remain the same all the time.)*

Comment: You should stick to one question per 'question'. 'How do I see XP status' and 'What is the XP requirement for each level' are different questions.

Comment: @Mufasa Thanks for the hint with separate questions. In this case your answer covers both .-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the **Dashboard** (<kbd>Tab</kbd> for keyboard, or `Start` for controller), then **Status** (<kbd>B</kbd> for keyboard, or `Y` on controller.). Your level and XP progress is in the top left.

[image: xp]

Fun fact tip: The Status screen is also the screen that lists your current buffs and ailments.